# Best practice or guidelines for writing AWS Lambda nodejs api

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I am creating serverless aws lambda functions for specific task. This lambda functions triggered by api  gateway. I found that creating manually one by one Lambda function then assign trigger for that function is time consuming and hard to maintain. Also I want reuse code at all.

I want to know is there any best practice, guidelines or pattern we should follow to make our work easier, code reusable across different lambda functions and code maintainable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes definitely if you are using serverless its worth using cloudFromation to create your environment for you [Template for lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-lambda.html)
2. Even you can use terraform which works on all cloud providers.
3. About reuse of code definitely you can put the functions in a common place and refer them in all lambda's that still makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly have a look at serverless framework 
https://serverless.com/ . There are a lot of options over there using `serverless.yml`